# Skeleton selection not avalible

Tags: docpad

```
info: Welcome to DocPad v6.63.3 (global installation: /usr/lib/node_modules/docpad)
info: Contribute: http://docpad.org/docs/contribute
info: Plugins:
info: Environment: development
info: Updating the exchange...
This can take a moment...
notice: An error occured fetching the exchange data, this is okay, but not all skeletons will be available to you undefined { timeout: 30000 }
info: You are about to create your new project inside your current directory. Below is a list of skeletons to bootstrap your new project:

  1.    No Skeleton
        Prefer to start from scratch? You can get started without any skeleton if you wish

Which skeleton will you use? [1-1]
  1.    No Skeleton
```

When I try to run the command "docpad run" I get the error above. I tried to install docpad in another computer and got the same error. How can I fix this?

Comment: Quite a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26339384/skeleton-list-isnt-available-with-docpad-run-command

Answer (score 0):

Install a newer version with

```
npm install docpad@6.63.8
```

Comment: Not a great answer. I'm getting this error with `$ docpad --version  
                                                                                                                               
v6.71.1 (global installation: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/docpad)`.