# Skeleton list isn't available with DocPad run command

Tags: docpad

When I use the command `d:\path>docpad run`, I have only one choice with Skeleton because I get an error when DocPad tried to updating exchange.

The output of this command:

```
D:\path>docpad run
info: Welcome to DocPad v6.69.1 (global installation: C:\Users\v20100v\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\docpad)
notice: If everyone who saw this message donated $1/week, maintaining DocPad would become sustainable: http://docpad.org/donate
info: Contribute: http://docpad.org/docs/contribute
info: Plugins:
info: Environment: development
info: Updating the exchange...
This can take a moment...
notice: An error occured fetching the exchange data, this is okay, but not all skeletons will be available to you undefined { code: 'ETIMEDOUT', errno: 'ETIMEDOUT', syscall: 'connect' }
info: You are about to create your new project inside your current directory. Below is a list of skeletons to bootstrap
your new project:

  1.    No Skeleton
        Prefer to start from scratch? You can get started without any skeleton if you wish

Which skeleton will you use? [1-1]
  1.    No Skeleton
>
```

Information about my configuration  :

```
-> Windows 7
-> node v0.10.13
-> npm v1.3.2
-> docpad v6.69.1
```

May be a proxy problem, but `node` and `npm` work fine with my configuration proxy.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: from my home network all works fine. 21 options to choose from.
- node 0.10.32
- npm 2.0.0
- docpad 6.63.3
- mac os

Comment: Yeah I'd recommend updating npm/node and then docpad and trying again. It's an interesting error.